# Scanning all elements of an array in GAWK returns numbers instead of values

Tags: arrays, string, gawk

Given the following function:

```
function process_pipes(text)
{
    split(text,recs,"|");
    for (field in recs){
        printf ("|%s|\n", field)
    }
}
```

If the input is: 0987654321|57300|ERROR account number not found|GDUMARESQ|0199|9|N|0||

Why do I get the numbers below instead of the text?

```
|4|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
|9|
|10|
|1|
|2|
|3|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` creates an array `recs` in your code, and `recs[1]` == 0987654321, etc.

The `for (field in recs)` loop generates the list of indexes, not the array elements.

Hence, you need:

```
function process_pipes(text)
{
    split(text,recs,"|");
    for (field in recs){
        printf ("|%s|\n", recs[field])
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  The example in the gawk manual isn't clear on that.  That leads me to ask why it doesn't process the array in order.

Comment: Because all arrays are treated as associative arrays, and the order seen is related to the order in which the keys present in the array are hashed.  There are sort functions in gawk (asrot, asorti) that can be used to get the data in sorted order - see: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
for ... in
```

gives you the *keys*. Use

```
printf("|%s|\n",recs[field]);
```

to get the values.